# Override Android Java Comparator Class

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have a base class which includes the following line to sort my objects ArrayList:

```
Collections.sort(objects, SortObjectList);
```

It also includes the following class definition to define the sort:

```
private class SortObjectList implements Comparator<T>
{
    public int compare(T lhs, T rhs) 
    {
        return lhs.name.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.name);
    }
}
```

In order to allow a derived class to sort using different criteria, I have implemented the following:

```
Collections.sort(objects, getSortObjectClass());
```

and

```
public Comparator<T> getSortObjectClass() {
    return new SortObjectList();
}
private class SortObjectList implements Comparator<T>
{
    public int compare(T lhs, T rhs) 
    {
        return lhs.name.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.name);
    }
}
```

I then override the sort in the derived class as follows:

```
@Override
public Comparator<MyDataClass> getSortObjectClass() {
    return new SortObjectList();
}
private class SortObjectList implements Comparator<MyDataClass>
{
    public int compare(MyDataClasslhs, MyDataClassrhs) 
    {
        return lhs.seqNo - rhs.seqNo;
    }
}
```

Which orders by seqNo rather than name.

It works, but seems a bit clunky. Does anyone know of a more elegant solution?

Comment: You should respect the Java naming conventions, and choose better names for your classes and methods. Variables start with a lower-case letter. Your method does not return a class, but a comparator instance, so why name it `getSortObjectClass()` and not `getComparator()` or `getListSorter()`?

Comment: @JB Nizet I'll rename the method getComparator() but which variable is not named to standard?

Comment: `Collections.sort(objects, SortObjectList)` should be `Collections.sort(objects, sortObjectList)` (or rather `Collections.sort(objects, comparator)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can make it *slightly* more compact using an anonymous inner class:

```
@Override
public Comparator<MyDataClass> getSortObjectClass() {
    return new Comparator<MyDataClass> {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyDataClass lhs, MyDataClass rhs)  {
            return lhs.seqNo - rhs.seqNo;
        }
    };
}
```

But that's about as compact as it gets in Java.

(Note that your comparison above will give the wrong result on overflow, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks, my seqNo's are all under my control so they won't overflow, or do you know something I dont? I'm not a Java expert!

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave: It's the subtraction which could overflow. Consider if `lhs.seqNo=Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `rhs.seqNo=1`.

Comment: If you compare a very large (like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) seqNo with a negative seqNo, you'll have an overflow (for example). Use Guava's `Ints.compare(int i1, int i2)` method to avoid this problem. Or `Integer.valueOf(i1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(i2))`.